# SetWorldSpawn Below Surface in MCJE 1.16

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I am currently trying to set the world spawn in a underground cave for my server(with `/setworldspawn`). However, when I tried `/kill` to test it, I ended up at the correct X and Z positions, however my Y level was at the surface. My friend recommended using beds, but I wanted new player to spawn there as soon as they join the server. Does anybody have a fix for this? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set your world spawn to a relative position by using this command:

```
/setworldspawn ~ ~ ~
```

This will make the world spawn where you are standing. You can also substitute the tildes (`~`) for the location you would like the player to spawn at in X Y Z coordinates if you'd like.

Comment: Thank you! I have been wondering about this for quite a while.

Comment: i believe you made a small typo-ish error so i have fixed it, but if i have changed the intent pls let me know

Comment: You can also use `/gamerule spawnRadius <value>` to set the "radius" around the location of the worldSpawn. If I remember correctly, a value of 0 means no radius (you will spawn exactly where you chose), and so on.

Comment: @Penguin Thanks for fixing that. I didn’t know what those were. 

Comment: @OKprogrammer oh, no problem. Well in that case I've made your answer better!